# phpMyadmin при авторизации кидает в корень домена

Tags: phpmyadmin

Поставил phpMyAdmin через стандартный

```
apt-get install phpmyadmin
```

В nginx прописал, чтобы он был доступен по адресу: mysite.ru/phpmyadmin 
заходит без проблем... но если вбить пользователя и пароль меня перекидывает в корень домена mysqite.ru + добавляется переменная ?token=*ХЕШ*
как быть? В какую сторону копать?

Answer (score 2):

В конфигурационный файл config.inc.php можно добавить параметр `PmaAbsoluteUri`, в который указать точный путь до корня phpMyAdmin на вашем сайте

```
$cfg['PmaAbsoluteUri'] = 'http://mysite.ru/phpmyadmin/';
```